# Does nested collections reduce cost of security rules in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Let's have a `children` collection, containing objects with property `parentId` where we need to restrict access to read objects to users having `parentId` in their token payload. For achieving this security rule may be as follows;

```
match /children/{childId} {
  allow read: if resource.data.parentId == request.auth.token.parentId;
}
```

If we restructure data by adding a super collection `parent` and placing its children as subcollection, security rule becomes;

```
match /parent/{parentId}/children/{childId} {
  allow read: if parentId == request.auth.token.parentId;
}
```

Does this structure reduce the query cost?

Comment: I don't see why that would reduce the cost. What makes you think so?

Comment: Well, I thought a query like `db.collection('parent/<some id>/children').get()` might have an optimization. @FrankvanPuffelen